# Can not enable TelePhone Permission from Application - Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, telephony, phone-call

I am trying to access call related use cases from my android application.
When the application run, I need to set the permission (Attached screen shot) for 'TelePhone' feature manually can not set it programmtically.

I have given the below permissions in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
```

How can I enable the permission from application itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about runtime permission please follow 
http://www.androidnovice.com/android-marshmallow-run-time-permissions/